# Optional Chaining Not Working As Expected

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code in my UIViewController subclass

```
class SideMenu: UIViewController {

  var contentViewController: UIViewController?

   override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {

        return contentViewController?.shouldAutorotate()

    }
}
```

But for some reason I get the following error:

> Value of optional type 'Bool?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '??'

[image: Screenshot of above error message on the return line]

I would expect that the optional chaining unwraps the optional, but this dosen't seem to be true? Am I wrong?

Comment: your function will return nil in the case that contentViewController is nil, either make the return type Bool? or use if let construct for the test, return false in the contentVC = nil case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of an optional chain is optional.  So `?.shouldAutorotate()` yields a `Bool?` while your function expects a `Bool`. Hence the error:

> Value of optional type 'Bool?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '??'

There are two possible solutions outlined by the error. One is to unwrap either with `contentViewController!.shouldAutorotate()` or `contentViewController?.shouldAutorotate()!` but both of these will crash if `contentViewController` was `nil` and that's not what you had in mind.

The other option is to provide a fallback value in case your `Bool?` is `nil`.  There's a nice operator for chaining: `??` which takes `T?` on the lefthand side and `T` on the righthand side.

That is, if you want to return false when contentViewController is nil you would return the following:

```
return contentViewController?.shouldAutorotate() ?? false
```

This is effectively the same behavior as the following code:

```
if let controller = contentViewController {
    return controller.shouldAutorotate()
} else { 
    return false
}
```